# Do you want a/one sandwich?

Tags: word-choice, determiners, exam-questions

I took an online English test, where a question was as follows:

> Do you want ___ sandwich or two?
>
> a) a
>   b) one

I chose option "a" but it was incorrect. We usually say "do you want a sandwich?", then why was my option incorrect?

Comment: This is just another one of those examples showing that "non-specialists" should probably avoid making up multiple-choice questions about valid English constructions like this. *I'm starving! I could go [a sandwich or two!](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+sandwich+or+two%22)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use **a/an** before singular countable nouns like *cat*, *dog*, **sandwich**, etc.

However, we use **one** rather than **a/an** if we want to emphasize that we are talking about only one thing or person rather than two or more:

> 1. Do you want **one** sandwich or two.

Therefore, the usage of **one** is correct here.

Similar examples are:

• Are you staying just **one** night.

• I just took **one** look at him and he started laughing.

Comment: Saying 'do you want a [thing] or two?' is perfectly natural conversational English. 'A sandwich or two' means 'a small number or sandwiches'. I am going camping; I shall take a sandwich or two.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, we say "an X or two" to mean "a small number". But we don't say, "Do you want an X or two?" to mean "Do you want one or do you want two?" When contrasing with "two", we say "one", not "a". If I asked someone, "Do you want a sandwich or two?", I would not be surprised if he answered "Yes", as in, yes, I would like one sandwich or maybe two. If I asked someone, "Would you like one sandwich or two?" I would expect him to answer either "one" or "two". An answer of "yes" would just be being deliberately difficult.

Comment: My mother, when serving gravy, used to say 'one lump or two?'.